# ExtendedEmailConfig with job dsl

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I am using job dsl to create jenkins jobs. I want to send emails out on job failures. I have already installed and configured 'ext-email' plugin. I have also added following section to my job DSL script

`extendedEmail('me@halfempty.org', 'Oops', 'Something broken')`

However I get following error

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.Job.extendedEmail() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [me@halfempty.org, Oops, Something broken]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:78)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
    at script1410384571000472680582$_run_closure1.doCall(script1410384571000472680582.groovy:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)

Any idea how can I get around it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the answer

`extendedEmail('me@halfempty.org', 'Oops', 'Something broken')` has to be wrapped inside publisher i.e. it should look like

`publisher {
  extendedEmail('me@halfempty.org', 'Oops', 'Something broken')
}`

Answer (score 1):

You can always refer to this [API](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/) there if you search a method you get the context in which it should present.. though you already got your answer but just to write so that it can help someone